# How to require JavaScript using webpack from a dynamic directory

Tags: webpack, require

I have some old-school plain old ES5 JavaScript that I need to pull into my application that is using webpack as a bundler. The problem is that the location of these files is in a folder whose path is dynamic. It seems that webpack does not work well with expressions in `require` and `require.context` doesn't allow them at all.

For known path directories to require all the files in a directory and its subdirectories, this approach **works fine**:

`let domainRequires = require.context('./app/domain', true, /\.js$/);
domainRequires.keys().forEach(domainRequires);`

Since I can't use an expression in `require.context`, I tried just using plain `require` and it is **NOT working**:

`require('../../path/to/code/my-library-' + versionNumber + '/domain/clazz.js');`

using the full relative path.

I've also tried to use `require.context` but enhancing the regex portion to get it working and haven't had luck:

`require.context('../../path/to/code', true, /^my-library-.*\/domain\/.*\.js$/);`

Any thoughts, suggestions, or solutions would be welcome. If I need to use something 3rd party with webpack, that's fine too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out. By using the webpack `resolve.alias`, I could add:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    common: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../path/to/code/my-library-' + versionNumber + '/domain')
  }
}
```

in `webpack.config`.

Then in my code, I can require all of the files under `/domain`via:

```
var commonRequires = require.context('common', true, /\.js$/);
commonRequires.keys().forEach(commonRequires);
```

Likewise, I could get a single file via:

```
require('common/clazz.js'); // ../../path/to/code/my-library-1.0.0/domain/clazz.js
```

FWIW, to get `versionNumber` I used node's `fs` module to read from a json file, used `JSON.parse(file)` and then retrieved the version at the top of `webpack.config`

Comment: What if  you have multiple dynamic variables? I need to require from a loop. This is a real pain. Don't know why they've made it so hard to implement...

Comment: This solution does require in a loop. See for the forEach. @tylik

Answer (score 0):

From Webpack 3.9 (I think) the `commonRequires` is not needed. I run this in webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    tmpDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '/tmp')
  }
}
```

And then I load my custom module as:

```
const dynModule = require('tmpDir/dyn_module.js');
```

Not sure if I miss something from your requirements but `commonRequires` is not needed for me and Webpack builds this just fine (and it works).

Comment: Hi @Anders, you are correct. The `commonRequires` is not related to the solution at all (I never intended it to be construed that way). This was just an example of requiring all files in a directory which was at a dynamic path. If you look back at the accepted answer you can see I also noted: "Likewise, I could get a single file via..."